# Why JSON object printed as String in JSP?

Tags: json, jsp, jsp-tags, json-lib

In my Servlet a JSONObject is created with the value:

```
{'alerts':true}
```

When I am trying to print its value on JSP page using , it is printing the JSON object as String . It is printed as

```
 "{'alerts':true}"
```

How do I print in JSON format rather than String?

In Servlet:

```
public JSONObject getAudioAlerts() {
    JSONObject val = new JSONObject("{'alerts':true}");
     return val;
}
```

In JSP:

```
<br><br><json:property name="audioAlerts" value="${myBean.audioAlerts"}" />;
    <br> Expected output: {'alerts':true}
    <br>Acutal output: "{'alerts':true}"
```

Comment: Can we get a view on your current source code?

Comment: you can parse your json string to json object like this var jsonObj = JSON.parse(audioAlerts);

Comment: @reporter edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @Gautam I don't want to use javascript just to parse this again on JSP page. Included source code in the question.

Comment: i can see method mismatch in jsp("getMailAudioAlertsEnabled") and servlet ("audioAlerts")

Comment: @Gautam rectified the mistake

Comment: I'm not sure , but I think you have to parse the output string into a json object, in javascript.

Comment: You should probably do something like : `return val.toJSONString();` and change `public JSONObject` for `public String`.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie The JSONObject class doesn't have a toJSONString() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html

**By setting the value="..." attribute on the tag.**  `<json:property/>`

- The same trimming and encoding rules apply as described above.
- If the value specified is a Boolean, then it will be converetd to a JSON boolean
- If the value specified is a number (Integer, Short, Long, Double, Float) then it will be - -converted to a JSON numeric value.
- If the value is a String it will be converted to a JSON string.
- Any other Java types that are used to set the value will have toString() called on them and they will be treated as JSON strings.

As per documentation your value is getting converted to Json String

so try to put your `<json:property>` into  `<json:object></json:object>`

or else you can parse your jSON string in javascript

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(audioAlerts)
```

Comment: i tried to put <json:property> into  <json:object></json:object>. It didn't work. Yes, JSON.parse() will work. But i am keeping that as my last resort.

Comment: Tried this <json:object value="${myBean.audioAlerts"/>. Server is throwing an error. <json:object><json:property name="audioAlerts" value = "${myBean.audioAlerts}"/></json:object>. Server is throwing error

Comment: i hope you added this in your code <%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>

Comment: please use only <json:object> tag

Comment: ya, the taglib is included and i tried using <json:object> with <json:property> tag embedded in it.